# Trouble inserting into cache

Tags: c#, caching

I'm trying to persist a list of objects between page redirects using `HttpContext.Current.Cache`. Here's what I have:

```
private string CACHE_KEY
{
    get
    {
        return "MyKey";
    }
}

protected List<object> SomeValue
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Cache[CACHE_KEY] == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(CACHE_KEY, 
                                             new List<object>(),
                                             null,
                                             DateTime.Today.AddMinutes(30),
                                             TimeSpan.Zero);
        }
        return (List<object>)HttpContext.Current.Cache[CACHE_KEY];
    }

    set
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(CACHE_KEY,
                                         value,
                                         null,
                                         DateTime.Today.AddMinutes(1),
                                         TimeSpan.Zero);
    }
```

}

When I try to retrieve `SomeValue`, `HttpContext.Current.Cache[CACHE_KEY]` is initially null, and let's say the cache item count is `n`. After the insert statement, the cache item count is `n + 1`, but when I check the results view, the **newly added item is missing**. Furthermore, `HttpContext.Current.Cache[CACHE_KEY]` is still null.

If that's not odd enough, here's a curveball... I have this same block of code (with a few minor differences) executing on another page in my site, and it works just fine. Can anyone tell me what's happening here?

Comment: Consider using the Runtime.Caching stuff instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because you use `DateTime.Today` instead of `DateTime.Now`.

`DateTime.Today` returns the current day *without* the current time. Whereas `DateTime.Now` returns both.

[**MSDN reference**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)